# Getting "This" into a namespace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, this

I'm sure this should be a simple question but I'm still learning so here it goes:

I have some code to run a function on click to assign the clicked element's ID to a variable but I don't know how to pass the "this.id" value to the namespace without making a global variable (which I thought was bad).

```
<script>
    fsa = (function() {

        function GetTemplateLoc() {
            templateId = document.activeElement.id;
            alert(templateId + templateId2);
        }


        return {
            GetTemplateLoc: GetTemplateLoc,
        }

    })();

    //call the functions
    $(document).on('click', '.template', function () {
        fsa.GetTemplateLoc();
    });
</script>
```

and HTML with random picture:

```
<img id="template-1" class="template" src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/028/c/b/cb21eda885b4cc6ee3f549a417770596.png"/>
<img id="template-2" class="template" src="http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/028/c/b/cb21eda885b4cc6ee3f549a417770596.png"/>
```

Comment: What about obvious `fsa.GetTemplateLoc(this.id);`?

Comment: Damn... of course. Thanks, as you can tell i've been programming for a few weeks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would work:

```
var fsa = (function() {
    function GetTemplateLoc() {
        var templateId = this.id;
        alert(templateId);
    }
    return {
        GetTemplateLoc: GetTemplateLoc,
    }
})();

//call the functions
$(document).on('click', '.template', fsa.GetTemplateLoc);
```

jQuery generally calls functions you pass as event handlers with `this` set to the DOM object the event is associated with.

In this case it will call `GetTemplateLoc()` with `this` set to either `.template` element, so you can use `this` directly in the function and don't need to pass any parameters.

Important tip: **Always** declare variables using `var`. JavaScript has no automatic function-local scope for variables, i.e. every variable declared without `var` is global, no matter where you declare it. In other words, forgetting `var` counts as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for that!  On a side note you've just fixed a few other bugs  because I didn't know about variables without var being global.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You can directly use `this.id` to pass id of the clicked element where `this` refers to the instance of clicked element.

```
<script>
    fsa = (function() {

        function GetTemplateLoc(templateId ) {
            //templateId = document.activeElement.id;
            alert(templateId + templateId2);
        }


        return {
            GetTemplateLoc: GetTemplateLoc,
        }

    })();

    //call the functions
    $(document).on('click', '.template', function () {
        fsa.GetTemplateLoc(this.id);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use jQuery within the `GetTemplateLoc` function, you could do something like this:

```
var fsa = (function() {

    function GetTemplateLoc($trigger) {
        var templateId = $trigger.attr('id'),
            templateId2 = $($trigger.siblings('.template')[0]).attr('id');
        alert(templateId + ' ' + templateId2);
    }


    return {
        GetTemplateLoc: GetTemplateLoc,
    }
})();

$(document).on('click', '.template', function () {
    fsa.GetTemplateLoc($(this));
});
```

You can set `GetTemplateLoc` to expect a jQuery object as a parameter (the dollar sign at the beginning of `$trigger` can be used to distinguish it as a jQuery object rather than any other data type, it's not necessary but can help clarify things sometimes).

`templateId` will store the value of the clicked image's ID, and `templateId2` will store the value of the other image's ID. I also added a space between the two variables in the alert.

If you can't use jQuery within `GetTemplateLoc`, you could do something like this:

```
var fsa = (function() {

    function GetTemplateLoc(trigger) {
        var templateId = trigger.id;

        var templateId2 = trigger.nextElementSibling == null ? trigger.previousElementSibling.id : trigger.nextElementSibling.id;

        alert(templateId + ' ' + templateId2);
    }

    return {
        GetTemplateLoc: GetTemplateLoc,
    }
})();
```

This time, the `.template` that triggered the event is passed into `GetTemplateLoc`, but this time it's not a jQuery object. `templateId` is assigned to the trigger's ID and then `templateId2` is assigned in a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). First, the `nextElementSibling` of `trigger` is checked to see if it's `null`. If it is, we know that `trigger` is the second of the two `.template` elements. Therefore we can set `templateId2` to the ID of `trigger`'s previous sibling. If `trigger`'s `nextElementSibling` is not `null`, then we know that `trigger` is the first template and we populate `templateId2` with the ID of `nextElementSibling`. This exact method will only work with two `.template`'s, if there are more you'll need some additional/different logic, probably to retrieve all `.template` IDs and then loop through them to add them to the alert message. Hope this helps.